# Postfix Evaluation C

Tags: c, arrays

I am having a great time trying to get this "calculator" type program to work.

I enter an arithmetic expression that is converted to postfix notation. (no biggie, I got that working yesteryear)

However, I cannot evaluate the damn postfix notation!  If you check out the first while loop in main you'll see thats where I get the segmentation fault.

If anyone has any idea I'd appreciate some pointers (lol).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains a lot of errors.

- `top` is defined as `-1` and you are accessing `stack[top]` for
  printing
- if you are printing a character at a particular index, not string
  then you have to use `%c` in the `printf` instead of `%s`
- You are not  modifying variable `j` inside the `while` loop also you are not intilaizing `j` before entering the loop

I corrected some of your mistakes and Please try this

```
  printf("\nPostfix Notation = %s\n",postnot);
  int j = 0;

 while((ch=postnot[j]) !='\0'){     //THIS IS WHERE I GET SEGMENTATION FAULT 
                           //CORE DUMPED WHILE DEBUGGING
    if(isdigit(ch))
    {
       push(ch - '0');
    }
   else
    {   op2=pop();
        op1=pop();
      switch(ch)
        {
            case '+':push(op1+op2);break;
            case '-':push(op1-op2);break;
            case '*':push(op1*op2);break;
            case '/':push(op1/op2);break;
        }
    }
    j++;
  }
  printf("\nANSWER= %d\n",pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int j;

while((ch=postnot[j]) !='\0')
```

You are not initialising `j`, so it could be anything between -2 billion and 2 billion. Furthermore I don't think the code will work because you're not incrementing j in the right scope.

Comment: @Rambi : you could have found it out by yourself if you had turned your compiler warnings all the way up (use `-Wall` with gcc). Your compiler is your friend ! If it complains, don't tell it to shut up, fix your code instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use "**" to flag errors in your code.  Use comments if you want to call reader attention to them in your example code.

Minor, but you are missing a header, ctype.h for isdigit().  Turn up your compiler warning levels to help you diagnose these things.

Don't attempt to increment this way: `j=j++;`  that is undefined behavior.  Just use `j++;` instead.

You should really never use gets().  It's a relic of a long time ago, and should not be used in new code.  From a man page for it:

> The gets() function cannot be used securely.  Because of its lack of
>   bounds checking, and the inability for the calling program to reliably
>   determine the length of the next incoming line, the use of this
>   function enables malicious users to arbitrarily change a running
>   program's functionality through a buffer overflow attack.  It is
>   strongly suggested that the fgets() function be used in all cases.

I think you should examine carefully what your attempt at a stack data structure does, especially the initialization before you call push/pop.  It's your responsibility to do bounds checking, and check for push() to a stack that is full, pop() from one that is empty, initialization of the stack for first use, etc.  Your code ignores those issues.

There is more, but I keep tripping on more places where you've made your example broken by dropping asterisks into it.

I can't help feeling you could have avoided this question, or at least gotten much further along on your own just by fixing the obvious compilation warning/error results first.